# Jquery fadein/out table row depending on ID

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I hope the title is clear, tried to search for something similar but couldn't really find it.

Alright so this is the code I have so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.collapsed-reorder').click(function(){

        $('.history-item').fadeToggle("500");
        $('.order-titels').fadeToggle("500");
        $(this).toggleClass('active-bar');
        $('.icon-right').attr('src',"images/icon-down.png");

    });
});
```

edit; forgot the HTML code.

```
    <tr class="collapsed-reorder" id="1">

            <td class="right-icon" colspan="2"><img class="icon-right" src="images/icon-right.png"> </td>
            <td colspan="1">#20234</td>
            <td colspan="1">29-07-15</td>
            <td colspan="8">2</td>
            <td class="repeat-order" colspan="2">Repeat order </td>

   </tr>

    <tr class="order-titels">

            <th colspan="8" class="item">ITEM</th>
            <th class="price">PRICE</th>
            <th class="qty">QTY</th>
            <th class="type">TYPE</th>
            <th class="sub-total">SUBTOTAL</th>
            <th class="your-price">YOUR PRICE</th>
            <th class="remove">REMOVE</th> 

     </tr>
            <tr class="history-item">

                //In here is a lot more data in td's, but I don't think that's relevant here.

            </tr>
```

And here is what it does right now (kind of obvious but yeah):
Whenever I click on the div collapsed-reorder, the div history-item and order-titels fades in and fades out when clicked again and adds a class to the div being clicked. This is working like it should, but there are going to be more div's with the name collapsed re-order, and more history-items. Every collapsed-reorder div has his own ID (1, 2, 3 etc.)

So my question is, how do I fade in/out the history-items that belong to the collapsed-reorder?

I'm not sure if I'm explaining it clearly, if not please let me know and I'll try to be more specific. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's the Fiddle, if that would actually help any haha. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7x5taLn9/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you looking for something like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.history-item').fadeToggle("500");
$(this).parent().find('.order-titels').fadeToggle("500");
$(this).toggleClass('active-bar');
$(this).parent().find('.icon-right').attr('src', "images/icon-down.png");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7x5taLn9/2/.

EDIT: If you want to do it in one table, use the $.next() function like so:

```
var $this = $(this);
var $currentEl = $this;
// Search for .history-items after this element and before the end of the parent element
while ($currentEl.next().length > 0 && !$currentEl.next().hasClass('collapsed-reorder')) {
    $currentEl = $currentEl.next();
    if ($currentEl.hasClass('history-item')) {
        $currentEl.fadeToggle("500");
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7x5taLn9/7/.

Comment: It does explain the idea of it, but it doesn't seem to work quite right. If I use that code it doesn't matter which collapsed-reorder DIV I click, it still fades in all the history-items

Comment: And I saw it did work in the Fiddle, but I guess it does because they are separate tables, I do need it to be in 1 table

Comment: @Stefan Then you'll need to update the fiddle with an actual use scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate, appreciate the help. Updated it to show the problem.

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander I updated my answer to reflect your clarified question.

Comment: That's amazing Adam, works like a charm! And I actually understand the code, thanks a lot mate!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Just be careful with while loops; if something unexpected happens, the loop will go on forever (causing the browser tab to freeze). You can prevent this by incrementing a counter and checking if the counter exceeds a certain set number (like 1000). If it does, `break;` out of the loop.